# Cakephp. How do i access other columns of a table if the only referenced column of that table is the id column

Tags: cakephp

i have TableA referencing id column of TableB as foreign key. The code below outputs the id of TableB, so i want to use this id to access the rest of the columns of this entity. How do i do that?

**Thi is the index.ctp  below**

```
<td><?= $tableA->has('tableB') ? $this->Html->link($tableA->$tableb_id->, ['controller' => 'TableA', 'action' => 'view', $tableA->TableB->id]) : '' ?></td>
```

Comment: using relationship belongsTo you can get that.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3.0 will attach associated tables to each Entity using an underscore singular naming convention (for BelongsTo, and underscore plural for hasMany) when using the contain feature.

So in your controller you would find records like this.

```
public function index() {
     $tableA = $this->TableA->find()->contain('TableB')->first();
     $this->set(compact('tableA'));
}
```

The above will find the first record, and also the associated TableB record. We can see this by using the debug feature.

```
     $tableA = $this->TableA->find()->contain('TableB')->first();
     debug($tableA->toArray());
```

In your view you can access the `TableB` as a property of $tableA

```
    // will output the association TableB
    debug($tableA->table_b_id); // the ID column
    debug($tableA->table_b); // all of TableB columns
```

You should learn the Cake bake features on the command line, as this will add `@property` annotations to the entity classes for associations.

You can bake `TableA` like this

```
$ bin/cake bake model TableA
```

Which will create `src/Model/Entity/TableA.php` and `src/Model/Table/TableATable.php`

For the `TableA.php` entity it will have a comment block like this.

```
/**
 * @property int id
 * // more properties
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\TableB $table_b
 */ 
class TableA extends Entity {
   // ...
}
```

As long as you follow Cake's conventions, and use the Bake features. A lot of this can be setup for you. Making it easier to find associated data. These `@property` features also enable autocomplete features in PhpStorm, Eclipse and other IDEs for PHP.

Comment: Thanks let me try that